# Javascript click and drag background not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a click and drag the background in Javascript, so I made [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w47gnaky/). But it has a problem.

When you click and drag to the left, the background moves to the right, so I track the position of the mouse, compare it to the mousedown, and with the difference I scroll the body. But, when it reaches to 0, the difference is negative so if you move past that difference and then move to the right again, you have to move the amount of pixels that you are past, which makes it weird.

So to fix this, I put this code:

```
if(difX < 0){
    md.x = mm.x;
}
```

which makes that, if the difference is less than 0 (i.e: reached the edge), the mousedown position is the same as the mousemove, so that when you move to the other side, the difference is no longer negative and can start increasing again.

The problem is that it jumps when you reach the edge.

I did this only with the X position, but I'll do the same for the Y once I solve it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, solved it out, the problem was the the `sl` variable didn't change when it reached a negative difference, so it used the one stored on mouseup and it jumped because of the difference between those numbers, [here's the solved fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eas84c6f/)